# Android - When scanning for bluetooth devices, is my device discoverable?

Tags: android, bluetooth

Quick question,
As the title says -
Is my device discoverable when it is searching for other discoverable devices?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you check the box to be discoverable(See your Bluetooth settings) your device will remain stealth during the search .

Answer (score 1):

No it is not - The radio can do only one thing at a time at the very lowest level. When scanning the process is continuous utilizing all the slots and nothing is available to perform any parallel activity

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so.

Searching doesn't require broadcasting, only receiving the beacon signals of other broadcasting devices.

Think of it like looking for WiFi. You can see the hotspots because they *want* you to, but you aren't really broadcasting your information in the process.